# Modify awk parameter with other command

Tags: awk

I have a file like this that contains multiple fields in lines. I want to display some of them, while processing one of them with another command.

```
TITLE,OpenVPN ...
HEADER,CLIENT_LIST,Common Name,Real Address,Virtual Address,Virtual IPv6 Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since,Connected Since (time_t),Username,Client ID,Peer ID
CLIENT_LIST,name1,1.1.1.1:1,10.0.0.1,,2692253,3765861,Wed Jun 23 12:51:08 2021,1624452668,name1,4727,0
CLIENT_LIST,name2,2.2.2.2:2,10.0.0.2,,1571221,2080242,Thu Jul  1 19:24:10 2021,1625167450,name2,5625,0
CLIENT_LIST,name3,3.3.3.3:3,10.0.0.3,,2670410,3736957,Wed Jun 23 16:20:51 2021,1624465251,name3,4747,0
...
```

The expected output is this:

```
name1  10.0.0.1  2021-06-23 12:51:08
name2  10.0.0.2  2021-07-01 19:24:10
name3  10.0.0.3  2021-06-23 16:20:51
```

The command I have now is this:

```
grep '^CLIENT_LIST,' /var/run/ovpn-server.status |awk -F',' '{print $2 $4 $9}' |sort
```

It prints the desired fields, but doesn't convert the timestamp to a formatted time. Here's the command for that:

```
date -d @1624452668 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

How can I integrate the `date` command into the `awk` script? Or what other solution is there to accomplish this?

I also intend to put the output into a columns/table layout with the `column` command, I've done that before, so that's not part of the question.

Comment: The expected output in your question is the formatted date from `$8` but the example `date` and `awk` commands you posted use `$9`. Which field is it you want converted - $8 (e.g. `Wed Jun 23 12:51:08 2021`) or $9 (e.g. `1624452668`)?

Comment: Actually both fields may produce the same output depending on your timezone. For me they're different.

Comment: I'm going to use the integer timestamp, that requires the `@` in front of it for `date`. Maybe I've counted it wrong.

Comment: No, your counting is fine and the epoch timestamp is in $9, it's just that the output those of us who aren't in your timezone see will then be different from the expected output you posted. Instead we will get the same output as you show if we use $8 instead of $9. That's fine to use the epoch timestamp from $9 if you prefer but by doing so you're forcing the solution to either use GNU awk for its `strftime()` extension or to be much slower than if you just used the text already present in $8 with any awk.

Comment: Speed doesn't matter here, it's just a dozen or so lines. And I prefer UTC for data sources, local time is just for the final display, and that time format there is... a mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '$1 == "CLIENT_LIST" {
   cmd = "date +\047%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\047 -d\047@" $9 "\047"
   print $2, $4, ((cmd | getline dt) > 0 ? dt : $9)
   close(dt)
}' file

name1   10.0.0.1    2021-06-23 08:51:08
name2   10.0.0.2    2021-07-01 15:24:10
name3   10.0.0.3    2021-06-23 12:20:51
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F, -v OFS='\t'`: Sets input field separator as `,` and output field separator as tab
- `'$1 == "CLIENT_LIST"`: Do it when first field is `CLIENT_LIST`
- `cmd = "date +\047%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\047 -d\047@" $9 "\047"`: Format `date` command using `$9`
- `cmd | getline dt` invokes external `date` command
- `(cmd | getline dt) > 0`: When `date` command is a success
- `print`: prints 2nd, 4th and output of `date` field

Comment: Nicely done. The comma-accounting is always the fun part when blending shell with awk.

Comment: The formatted time seems to have some leading space, it doesn't align in the `column` output. Also, some explanation would be appreciated as I don't understand what that script does and why it actually works. What are `{`, `cmd =`, the parentheses, `close` and `dt`?

Comment: I have added explanation in answer. Let me know if there is any specific query.

Comment: Worked great yesterday. Strangely, today (on a freshly installed Pi) it fails to resolve half of the timestamps. Giving the numbers to the date command manually works. But not in awk anymore. I have no idea why. date always returns 0, which is good.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some sample data in question for which this solution isn't working?

Comment: The sample data is the same as in my question above. I cannot share the full file for privacy but it has the exact same structure, no additional commas or spaces or anything. Some lines have dates, some the raw number. Anyway, I changed my code to not use awk and do it in a loop in bash instead. It's easier to understand, at the same code length. I just thought that it would be simple in awk, but it isn't.

Comment: `awk` is simpler and less error prone than `bash` loop but most likely there is some data variance that is not reflected in sample data provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually just want the date+time from `$8` reformatted instead of converting the seconds since the epoch from `$9` to a date+time then you can just do the following which will be orders of magnitude faster than calling `date` since that would require `awk` to spawn a subshell once per input line to call `date` from that subshell which would be extremely slow.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
NR > 2 {
    split($8,t," ")
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3
    print $2, $4, sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %s", t[5], mthNr, t[3], t[4])
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
name1   10.0.0.1        2021-06-23 12:51:08
name2   10.0.0.2        2021-07-01 19:24:10
name3   10.0.0.3        2021-06-23 16:20:51
```

or if you really want to use the epoch seconds from $9 then use GNU awk for `strftime()` so you don't have to spawn subshells to call `date` (but note that the output now becomes TZ-dependent, just like with `date`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
NR > 2 {
    print $2, $4, strftime("%F %T",$9)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
name1   10.0.0.1        2021-06-23 07:51:08
name2   10.0.0.2        2021-07-01 14:24:10
name3   10.0.0.3        2021-06-23 11:20:51
```

```
$ TZ=UTC awk -f tst.awk file
name1   10.0.0.1        2021-06-23 12:51:08
name2   10.0.0.2        2021-07-01 19:24:10
name3   10.0.0.3        2021-06-23 16:20:51
```

or setting the UTC flag in strftime() if UTC is what you have in your data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
NR > 2 {
    print $2, $4, strftime("%F %T",$9,1)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
name1   10.0.0.1        2021-06-23 12:51:08
name2   10.0.0.2        2021-07-01 19:24:10
name3   10.0.0.3        2021-06-23 16:20:51
```